# The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open

Tags: java, windows, db2

I am writing a batch file with the command `db2cmd/c /w /i db2 DROP DATABASE xyz` with DB2 and Windows 7 through java.
`db2cmd` is unable to delete the database and returns the error:

> The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open

How do I fix this?

and 
There are no open connections present while executing the command as this command is creating problem only in windows 7.

Comment: i assume this has nothing to do with java, Does it fail if you manually execute this from the command line?

Comment: ya you are right it is related to window but i have mention all the context to help to understand the problem.......yes i have tried it but it get same error msg,

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that there are open connections to the database that are blocking the operation. Try issuing these commands first:

```
db2 CONNECT TO xyz
db2 QUIESCE DB IMMEDIATE FORCE CONNECTIONS
```

Here are details on the [QUIESCE command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008635.html).